ci4, problem with displaying activities according to today
I use code igniter 4.
I want to make a feature where it displays the extracurricular activities that are currently scheduled for today based on database Column 1 (primary key), column 2 means extracurricular in Indonesia language, column 3 means day in Indonesia language
So when I run, it appears notification error when I add line code p>Hari ini adalah:  
But when I erase it, it runs well without that feature Run well without feature day
You can also see my repo github in My github repo
I want to run the line code
p>Hari ini adalah: <?= esc($hari); ?></p> <!-- Menampilkan hari ini -->

Whats does the code mean?
In that code I want to show the extracurricular who has a schedule for today based on SQL database

Please do not post images of code/data/errors.

Welcome to SO.  I'd suggest starting with some PHP and Codeigniter tutorials.  Passing variables to views is covered in the first few paragraphs of the very first page of the CI getting started guide: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

The $hari variable (or $hariini in your repo) in that line is used to display the name of today (monday, tuesday, etc in Indonesian). You need to pass a value for this variable from your controller to this view.
Looking at your repo, you already seem to have the code that gets the name of today in EkstraController::index.
And you also have a model function that gets the activities for a given day, ModelEkstra::getEkstraByDay.
Using these in your Ekstrakurikulercontroller should get you the result you want:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\ModelEkstra; // Use the other model
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Ekstrakurikulercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $namaHari = [
            'Sunday' => 'Minggu',
            'Monday' => 'Senin',
            'Tuesday' => 'Selasa',
            'Wednesday' => 'Rabu',
            'Thursday' => 'Kamis',
            'Friday' => 'Jumat',
            'Saturday' => 'Sabtu'
        ];

        $hariInggris = date('l');
        $hari = $namaHari[$hariInggris];
        $data['hariini'] = $hari; // Set the hariini variable for the view
    
        // Get the activities for today
        $model = new ModelEkstra();
        $data['ekstrakurikuler'] = $model->getEkstraByDay($hari);

        return view('ekstrakurikuler_view', $data);
    }
    // ...
}


ow. ow. ow. thank you so much!!! i spent 4 days just to finish this, after i changed it there was still error but after i removed the paragraph that called $hari in the view, it worked as i wanted!!. thank you so much!!!

You're welcome! If you're using a $hari variable in the view (and not a $hariini one like the view has in the repo), change this line $data['hariini'] = $hari; to $data['hari'] = $hari;
